# Netsuite Token Based Authentication, Invalid Login Attempt

Tags: c#, .net, soap, token, netsuite

I am trying a NetSuite integration (SOAP), with Token-Based Authentication, and always get "Invalid Login attempt", all the credentials are right, when I am trying a get request to:
"https://accountid.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2017_1", I receive :

[image]
This is my c# code :

```
        public static void Get()
        {
            var nonce = ComputeNonce();
            var timeStamp = ComputeTimestamp();
            var customer = new Customer();

            var tokenPassport = new TokenPassport()
            {
                account = Account,
                consumerKey = ConsumerKey,
                token = TokenId,
                nonce = nonce,
                timestamp = timeStamp,
                signature = new TokenPassportSignature()
                {
                    Value = GetEncodedSignature(nonce, timeStamp),
                    algorithm = "HMAC_SHA256"
                }
            };

            var netsuiteclient = new NetSuitePortTypeClient();

            var res = netsuiteclient.getAsync(null, tokenPassport, null, null, null, new RecordRef()).Result;
}

        public static string GetEncodedSignature(string nonce, long timeStamp)
        {
            string baseString = $"{Account}&{ConsumerKey}&{TokenId}&{nonce}&{timeStamp}";
            string secretKey = $"{ConsumerSecret}&{TokenSecret}";

            HMACSHA256 hashObject = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));

            byte[] signature = hashObject.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(baseString));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);

        }

        private static string ComputeNonce()
        {
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] data = new byte[20];
            rng.GetBytes(data);
            int value = Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0));
            return value.ToString();
        }
        private static long ComputeTimestamp()
        {
            return ((long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds);
}
```

Could somebody help, Thank you !

Comment: Where are the other headers that you need to set?

Comment: Just as an FYI--netsuite already has a few netsuite examples that you can use.  https://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-sample-applications.shtml